# How to let mobile users know that an embedded YouTube video is loading slowly

Tags: user-behavior, video

I have a video that's embedded in a landing page [www.druckxthegame.eu](http://www.druckxthegame.eu)  On desktops, it works great because the video loads instantly. But on mobile, the video takes more time to load and during the wait time some users may not even see that there's video loading. What would be a good solution so that users see there's a video loading?

Comment: What you came with to solve this issue? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

All Smartphones have a built in visual representation for showing that data is loaded at the very top left. It is often represented by some kind of a rotating object, such as the following animated gif.

[image]

But if you make it more obvious to the user if you replace the video with a progress bar while loading data, and switch to video when all is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a spinning indicator spinning at a speed proportional to the loading speed. They use pretty much the same paradigm on iOS to make the speed difference clear between 3G (and faster) connection and Edge.